# click anywhere except a specified class including its children

Tags: jquery

Here alert appears if I click on `.m1wrap` children, but I need to show the alert if there is a click anywhere except on `.m1wrap` AND ALL ITS CHILDREN.

```
<div class="m1wrap">
<div class="m1top"></div>
<div class="m1bottom"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target.className !== "m1wrap") {
        alert ("323");
    };
})
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314, I included a simple version of html. There are two divs inside `m1wrap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) with selector `".m1wrap, .m1wrap *"` to select parent `.m1wrap` and children of `.m1wrap`

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).is(".m1wrap, .m1wrap *")) {
        alert ("323");
    };
})
```

```css
.m1wrap, .m1wrap * {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  width:100px;
  padding:2px;
}

.m1top {
  position:absolute;
  left:120px;
}

.m1bottom {
  position:absolute;
  left:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="m1wrap">
  m1wrap
<div class="m1top">m1top</div>
<div class="m1bottom">m1bottom</div>
</div>
```